# String components(separatedBy: <CharacterSet>) Swift4

Tags: ios, swift

I have some query regarding documentation provided by apple at this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string

Why documentation doesn't contain `components(separatedBy:)` method . Instead inside "Splitting a String" section new method `split(separator:maxSplits:omittingEmptySubsequences:` is added by apple.

Comment: `Why documentation doesn't contain components(separatedBy:) method` Because `components(separatedBy:)` is for NSString, not for String - it's in Foundation, not in Swift itself.

Comment: if this method is in NSString then how can we call `components(separatedBy:)` directly on String without casting it to NSString. Please help in understanding this.

Comment: There's nothing special to do because NSString is "bridged" to String. You can call `components(separatedBy:)` directly on a String. *But* the method is not declared in Swift, it is declared in Foundation, that's the difference.